# Skyrim Lydia missing

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I told Lydia to wait near the bridge at whiterun so I could go kill some giants, in my way I encountered a dragon and when I go back to the bridge I can't seem to find her there? What do I do?

Comment: Are you playing on the PC version or on a console? If you're playing on PC you can use console commands to teleport Lydia to your position.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you fast travel, Lydia should appear next to you.

Answer (score 0):

First you can try **Fast Travel**. She should be transported right next to you.

If it doesn't work, check your **house** or the Jarl's Palace in Whiterun, and maybe sleep or wait there for three days.

If you still cannot find her... she probably died, sorry.